# format well defined string to an object using es5

Tags: javascript, string

I have either of these string:

`var str = "Apple Banana Kiwi Orange: fruit. Tomato: vegetable"`

or

`var str = "Tomato: maybe a fruit. Apple Banana Orange: fruit. Carrots: vegetable"`.

I want to format it to an object of this format only using ES5.

```
{
Apple: "fruit",
Banana: "fruit",
Kiwi: "fruit",
Orange: "fruit",
Tomato: "vegetable"
}
```

I tried a combination of using `split()` and nested `for` loop, but I'm not sure it's the best solution.

Comment: What was wrong with it? If you want help fixing it, you need to post what you've written.

Comment: And if it works but you're looking for suggestions to improve it, [codereview.se] would be the place to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some time and quickly wrote something and relies heavily on whitespace. You may want to make sure you clean your input on each step but I leave that up to you.

```js
function myFormatter(input) {
  var result = {};
  
  input.split('. ').forEach(function(bit) {
    var a = bit.split(': ');
    var keys = a[0];
    var value = a[1];
    
    keys.split(' ').forEach(function(thisKey) {
      result[thisKey] = value;
    });
  });
  
  return result;
}

console.log(myFormatter('Apple Banana Kiwi Orange: fruit. Tomato: vegetable'));

console.log(myFormatter('Tomato: maybe a fruit. Apple Banana Orange: fruit. Carrots: vegetable'));
```

Comment: This solution is closer to what I implemented but more cleaner. Thanks!